# How to extract country codes from phone number?

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I'm trying to extract the country codes and move them into a new column.

**Example data**

```
data <- data.frame(phone = c("+1 800 000 000", "+257000000000", "+91-00 000 00", "200000 000"))
```

I only have a start so far. For instance, I can extract the `+` sign, but I'm trying to find how to detect `+1 +257 +91`, etc..

```
data |> 
  mutate(country_code = str_extract(phone, "[:symbol:]"))
```

```
phone            country_code
+1 800 000 000      +           
+257000000000       +           
+91-00 000 00       +           
200000 000          NA
```

**What I'm trying to achieve:**

```
phone            country_code
+1 800 000 000      +1          
+257000000000       +257            
+91-00 000 00       +91         
200000 000           NA
```

I'm wondering if I can match possible country codes based on another vector where I specify the different variations, like this: `codes <- c(1, 257, 91)` or like this `codes <- c("+1", "+257", "+91")`.

Comment: The country codes are of varying lengths, how would you differentiate between country and area codes?

Comment: Good, question. I may have to handle that part manually. I'll update the question.

Comment: Do you have a set number of countries/country codes you are working with? ie, `codes <- c("+91", "+257", "+1")'

Comment: There are probably 10. I've added 3 of them in the updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

data %>% mutate(country_code = str_extract(phone, str_c('\\+', codes, collapse = '|')))
           phone country_code
1 +1 800 000 000           +1
2  +257000000000         +257
3  +91-00 000 00          +91
4     200000 000         <NA>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `+` is a special character, you have to add `\\` to escape it. You can try searching for any of your pre-designated codes by first concatenating all of them using the "or " symbol (`|`) then using the `stringr` package's `str_match`:

```
srch <- paste0("\\",paste(codes, collapse = "|\\"))
# [1] "\\+1|\\+257|\\+91"

stringr::str_match(data$phone, srch)
```

Output:

```
     [,1]  
[1,] "+1"  
[2,] "+257"
[3,] "+91" 
[4,] NA
```

Data

```
data <- data.frame(phone = c("+1 800 000 000", "+257000000000", "+91-00 000 00", "200000 000"))
codes <- c("+1", "+257", "+91")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `base R`

```
pat <- sprintf("\\+(%s)", paste(codes, collapse = "|"))
i1 <- grepl(pat, data$phone)
data$country_code[i1] <-  regmatches(data$phone[i1], regexpr(pat, data$phone[i1]))
```

-output

```
> data
           phone country_code
1 +1 800 000 000           +1
2  +257000000000         +257
3  +91-00 000 00          +91
4     200000 000         <NA>
```